# Tic Tac Toe - Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game in Java and I need to set the "X" value so that on the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th and 9th turn an X is placed in the boxes and when it's the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th turn a "O" is placed. If anyone could help it would greatly appreciated

I tried using a counter:

```
public void onClick(View event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event == btnBox1) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 0) {
            btnBox1.setText("X");
            btnBox1.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (counter == 1) {
            btnBox1.setText("O");
            btnBox1.setEnabled(false);
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried using a counter: "public void onClick(View event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (event == btnBox1){
   counter++;
   if (counter == 0){
    btnBox1.setText("X");
    btnBox1.setEnabled(false);
   }
   if (counter == 1){
    btnBox1.setText("O");
    btnBox1.setEnabled(false);
   }"

Comment: use a boolean variable like `xTurn` or something.. set it to true initially and then modify it every turn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

- the [remainder or modulus](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/) `%` operator. It returns the remainder of the division of two numbers. `counter % 2` will be 1 if counter is odd and 0 if counter is even.
- the [bitwise AND operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) `&`, suggested by  Mr. Polywhirl. You could also do `(n & 1) == 0` (bit-wise AND) to check for even.

Using the modulus operator, your method will be:

```
public void onClick(View event) { 
    if (event == btnBox1){ 
        counter++; 
        if (counter % 2 == 0){ 
            btnBox1.setText("X"); 
            btnBox1.setEnabled(false); 
        }
        if (counter % 2 == 1){
            btnBox1.setText("O");
            btnBox1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could also do `(n & 1) == 0` (bit-wise AND) to check for even. This tends to be much faster than modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I didn't think about it! Thanks! I modified my answer.